# Spring Security don't change role

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I wrote a project where the admin can change the role of the user (from user to admin level). I kind of wrote the code correctly, but it does not change the role. You can see the code. The login changes, but the user's role remains the same as it was before.

[image]

EditUser.JSP

```
<body>
<center>
    <h1>User Edit form</h1>

    <form:form method="POST" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/editUser">
        <table>
            <input type="hidden" value="${user.id}" name="id"/>
            <tr>

                <td><label path="Login">Login</label></td>
                <td bgcolor="#000000"><input type="text" name="login" value="${user.login}"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label path="Password">Password</label></td>
                <td bgcolor="#000000"><input name="password" value="${user.password}"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select name="role">
                        <option value="${user.role}" selected>ROLE_ADMIN</option>
                        <option value="${user.role}">ROLE_USER</option>
                </td>
                </select>


            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
</center>
```

UserServiceImpl.JAVA

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;


    @Autowired
    public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository repository) {
        super();
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> getAll() {
        return (List<User>) repository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<User> findUser(Long id) {
        return repository.findById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public User saveUser(User user) {
        return repository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public User updateUser(User user) {
        User targetUser = repository.findById(user.getId()).get();

        if (user.getLogin() != null) {
            targetUser.setLogin(user.getLogin());
        }

        if (user.getRole() != null) {
            targetUser.setRole(user.getRole());
        }

        if (user.getPassword() != null) {
            targetUser.setPassword(user.getPassword());

        }
        return repository.save(targetUser);


    }
}
```

User.JAVA

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable, UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String login;
    private String password;
    private String role;
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return Collections.singleton(new SchoolAuthority(role));
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return login;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    class SchoolAuthority implements GrantedAuthority {

        String role;

        public SchoolAuthority(String role) {
            this.role = role;
        }

        @Override
        public String getAuthority() {
            return role;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
        "id=" + id +
        ", login='" + login + '\'' +
        ", password='" + password + '\'' +
        ", role='" + role + '\'' +
        '}';
    }
}
```

AdminController.JAVA

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class AdminController {

    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentService;
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/allStudentsAdmin")
    public ModelAndView allStudentsForUser() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        List<Student> studentList = studentService.getAllStudents();
        mv.addObject("studentList", studentList);
        mv.setViewName("allStudentsAdmin");
        return mv;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/deleteStudent/{id}")
    public ModelAndView deleteUserById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        studentService.deleteStudentById(id);
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:/admin/allStudentsAdmin");
        return mv;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/editStudent/{id}")
    public ModelAndView displayEditUserForm(@PathVariable Long id) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("adminEditStudent");
        Student student = studentService.getStudentById(id);
        mv.addObject("headerMessage", "Редактирование студента");
        mv.addObject("student", student);
        return mv;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/editStudent")
    public String saveEditedUser(
    @RequestParam("id") Long id,
    @RequestParam("name") String name,
    @RequestParam("surname") String surname,
    @RequestParam("avatar") MultipartFile file) {
        try {
            studentService.updateStudent(name, surname, file, studentService.getStudentById(id));
        } catch (FileSystemException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "redirect:/errors";
        }

        return "redirect:/admin/allStudentsAdmin";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/addStudentAdmin")
    public ModelAndView displayNewUserForm() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("addStudentAdmin");
        mv.addObject("headerMessage", "Add Student Details");
        mv.addObject("student", new Student());
        return mv;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/addStudentAdmin")
    public String saveNewStudent(@RequestParam("name") @NonNull String name,
    @RequestParam("surname") @NonNull String surname,
    @RequestParam("avatar") MultipartFile file)
    throws IOException {

        Student student = new Student();
        student.setSurname(surname);
        student.setName(name);

        if (file != null && !file.isEmpty()) {
            student.setAvatar(studentService.saveAvatarImage(file).getName());
        }
        studentService.saveStudent(student);
        return "redirect:/admin/allStudentsAdmin";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/addUser")
    public ModelAndView displayAddUserForm() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("addUser");

        mv.addObject("user", new User());
        return mv;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/addUser", consumes = "multipart/form-data")
    public String saveNewUser(@ModelAttribute User user) {
        userService.saveUser(user);
        return "redirect:/admin/allUsers";
    }

    @GetMapping("/allUsers")
    public ModelAndView allUsers(@ModelAttribute User user) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("allUsers");
        List<User> users = userService.getAll();
        mv.addObject("users", users);
        return mv;
    }

    @GetMapping("/editUser/{id}")
    public ModelAndView editUser(@PathVariable Long id) {
        Optional<User> user = userService.findUser(id);
        if (user.isPresent()) {
            ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("editUser");
            mv.addObject("user", user.get());
            return mv;
        }
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/admin/allUsers");
    }

    @PostMapping("/editUser")
    public String saveEditedUser(@ModelAttribute User user) {
        userService.updateUser(user);
        return "redirect:/admin/allUsers";
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that role was updated successfully on Database?

Comment: I used to change it, but now it does not change

Answer (score 1):

Your jsp code contains an error in the code below:

```
 <select name="role">
    <option value="${user.role}" selected>ROLE_ADMIN</option>
    <option value="${user.role}">ROLE_USER</option>
```

The parameter role always have the same value `${user.role}`. If you choose ROLE_ADMIN or ROLE_USER, the value of current user role (`${user.role}`) always be sent to controller.